# Why was Brandon denied entry to the night club?

Tags: plot-explanation, shame

Near the end of the movie [Shame](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1723811/), Brandon tries to enter a night club (or something), and is denied entry by the bouncer who says:

> Not tonight.
>
> I said, not tonight.

What establishment was he trying to enter?  And why was he denied entry?

Answer (score 4):

> What establishment was he trying to enter?

The name of the club was "Score":

[image]

Going by the [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=score) definition and Brandon's choices before and after the bouncer's refusal of entry, I have a feeling it was a sex club.

> And why was he denied entry?

This answer was not was clear.  Brandon was trying to sneak past him so I would guess he'd been there before.  It seems to me whatever moral or legal "rules" he'd broken previously, the Bouncer enforced his suspension.

Comment: It was not, as far as I can tell, a sex club. That is also not the reason he was denied entry, at least according to the screenplay.

Answer (score 2):

In [the script](https://indiegroundfilms.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/shame.pdf) we see Brandon taking a punch to the face only a short time before. He's described as having had his...

> face smashed against the sidewalk.

...he's been crying and is...

> aimless and bleeding[.]

He attempts to sneak past the bouncer into the *'lively bar'* with his (bruised) face hidden, but gets noticed. The bouncer, rightly, assumes that he's been in a fight and isn't the sort of person they want in their nightclub.

> EXT. STREET NEAR CLUB. NIGHT.
>
> A lively bar; a couple of HOT GIRLS entering
>
> BRANDON considers, goes to enter, barred by BOUNCERS, who point him back along the cue
>
> He stands in line
>
> Across the street, a THICK SET GUY eyes him. He stands smoking outside a heaving bar. BRANDON looks away
>
> A GANG OF GIRLS pass, The BOUNCERS let them in with ease. **BRANDON reaches for his iPhone, tries to cover his face with his phone to get into the club**
>
> **BOUNCER** *Woah! Not tonight, buddy.*
>
> BRANDON tries to get in again
>
> The BOUNCER stops him a second time
>
> **BOUNCER (CONT’D)** *I said not tonight.*